# Read a specific column of a certain cell range and store the values using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, list, pandas, cell

I am trying to figure out a way to read data from a specific column from a certain cell range and store it into a array using pandas.

For example my Excel sheet consists of :

---

test |    p

Food|   Price

Chicken|    8.54

Beef  |6.73

Vegetables|   3.2

### Total Price |18.47

Note: there is a an empty space on the first row for a reason.
Note: | indicates cell separation.

I am trying to get the price values which start from Row B3 to row B5 and store them into an array via [8.54,6.73,3.2].

So far the code I have is:

```
import pandas as pd

xl_workbook = pd.ExcelFile("readme.xlsx")  # Load the excel workbook
df = xl_workbook.parse("Sheet1")  # Parse the sheet into a dataframe
x1_list = df['p'].tolist()  # Cast the desired column into a python list
print(x1_list)
```

Which then results to [nan, u'price',8.54,6.73,3.2]

If I just wanted to read the values 8.54, 6.73, and 3.2, to result in [8.54,6.73,3.2] how would I do this?

Is there a way to grab a certain column of a certain cell range?

Comment: wouldn't slicing work for you? Ex - `x1_list = df['p'].tolist()[2:]`

Comment: Do you need this in a list? `df['p'].iloc[1:]` will give you a series, `df['p'].iloc[1:].tolist()` will give you the same as a list

Comment: Possibly I will try but what would I use to reference a specific column per say if the first row was completly empty? I could not use x1_list = df['p'].tolist()  correct?

Comment: @EdChum, how would I be able to do it if p wasnt there for example if the first row was just empty?

Comment: It should still be assigned an ordinal value so if second column then `df[1].iloc[1:]` should work

Comment: @EdChum, Sorry if I am not being understanding, but when i set x1_list= df[4].iloc[1:]  I see that it outputs  [8.54,6.73,3.2,18.47] If i just want the list to stop before the last data on that column "18.47" and just output the list into [8.54,6.73,3.2] how would I go about doing that?

Comment: `set x1_list= df[4].iloc[1:4]`

Comment: @EdChum, Is seems to give me a bunch of errors when I do this. I believe this has to do with the 'df[4]'. df['p'] works with no errors but df[4], bring a lot.

Comment: the syntax here is that it's trying to find a column with that specific value, it's unclear to me what your columns actually are when you read the excel in, you can see the values yourself by doing `df.columns.tolist()`, if it can't find a header row then it auto generates ordinal integer values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, you could use [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) in Pandas.  This assumes you have consistent formatting.

```
import pandas as pd

# define the file name and "sheet name"
fn = 'Book1.xlsx'
sn = 'Sheet1'

data = pd.read_excel(fn, sheetname=sn, index_col=0, skiprows=1, header=0, skip_footer=1)
```

Comment: Thanks I will definitely give that a try . C:

Comment: I tried this code but I received an error saying : parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sheetname'

Comment: What version of Pandas are you using?  I am on 16.2